# Sticky Navbar shaking and sloppy when overflow elements pass underneath it?

Tags: css

I'm sure this is a simple question, but I am having issues.

So the sticky head and footer do what they're supposed to but the amount of jumping and shaking that happens when elements pass underneath the header or footer is absolutely insane, it looks like total crap, so there is absolutely something I am doing wrong here. Doesn't matter the browser, all the same. What am I missing here?

```
<div id="inner-media-user">
     <div class="top-nav-header">Hello</div>
     <div id="ajax_payload">Elements</div>
     <div class="bot-nav-footer">Goodbye</div>
</div>

#inner-media-user {
  height:400px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  z-index:100;
}
.top-nav-header {
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}
.bot-nav-footer { 
  position:sticky;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:100;
}
#ajax_payload {
  padding:5px;
  z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: Can you share a fiddle that's showing your problem?

Comment: [I've pasted your code](https://jsfiddle.net/a1mf6pzb/) and I see no shaking.

Comment: It's most likely the elements then, let me edit my question.